# JSON data not making it to service using httpntlm post in node.js

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, node.js, node-modules

I am trying to send a JSON payload to a ASP.NET MVC action that has a JsonResult.  When I debug the action I am finding that the JSON data does not seem to be coming through.  I have tried both letting the MVC do the deserialization to a custom object parameter and accepting a string parameter that I would then deserialize within the method.  In both cases the parameter is coming in null.  Below are both the MVC action signature and the node code I'm using to call the action.

**Action signature**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyAction(MyCustomClass parm)
```

**Node code**

```
var httpntlm = require('httpntlm');

var requestStructure = {
    sfId: '000000000000000',
    emails:[{
            Id: '2',
            Label: 'asdfesed',
            EmailAddress: 'me@mydomain.com'
        }]
}

httpntlm.post({
    url: "http://localhost:63102/MyController/MyAction",
    username: 'me',
    password: 'pwd',
    workstation: 'choose.something',
    domain: '',
    json: requestStructure

}, function (error, response) {
    console.log('error ' + error)
    console.log('status ' + response.statusCode)
    console.log('body ' + response.body)
});
```

I really haven't found any examples of using httpntlm for a POST.  I'm sure I'm missing something but can't seem to figure out what.  If there is a site that has good documentation for this please point me in that direction.

Comment: Would it be possible for you specify the contentType of your request body to "application/json" ?

Comment: I was looking at that, but it was unclear where in the Post parameters that should be set.  Should it just be added to the options list?  On the normal httpreq module I believe that is normally in a separate headers list.

Comment: I tried adding the contentType and the data is still coming through null with both approaches to receiving it.    `headers: { contentType: 'application/json' },`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the service and not the caller.  The service was a pseudo Web API action off of a MVC controller.  I put the method in a separate ApiController and the values showed up.